# AlamofireImage 2.0 sessionManager issue

Tags: alamofire, alamofireimage

I am using the new AlamofireImage 2.1.0 version in my app and when trying to clear the image cache using

```
imageDownloader.sessionManager.session.configuration.URLCache?.removeCachedResponseForRequest(URLRequest)
```

I am receiving an error:

```
Value of type 'ImageDownloader' has no member 'sessionManager'
```

I am also using Alamofire 3.1.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sessionManager` property on `ImageDownloader` has an internal ACL in the `2.1.0` release. I've recently changed the ACL to `public` in [f35e4748](https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage/commit/f35e4748a05039e47367b11174d6d6c8c26bcf5f) which is sitting in the `master` branch. If you update to `master`, your code sample should work as expected.

> We'll get the `2.1.1` release cut here within the next couple of days.

Comment: Cool. I can wait. No rush. Lots of others things to do ;)

Comment: Cool dude...if there's nothing else you're looking for, could you mark as the answer and upvote?